# Equivalent of timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate in android

Tags: android

Is there a method to calculate the time interval with respect to a date, much similar to the timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate in iPhone?
thanks..

Answer (score 7):

`System.currentTimeMillis()` returns the number of milliseconds since midnight January 1 1970 as a `long`.

Comment: Correct. However, note that the "reference date" on Mac OS X/iOS is January 1, 2001 12:00AM UTC, while the POSIX epoch is January 1, 1970 12:00AM UTC. On Mac OS X/iOS, to get the interval since the POSIX epoch, use `+[NSDate timeIntervalSince1970]`. :)

Comment: @Jonathan Grynspan: However, there is nothing built into Android that considers 1/1/2001 to be a reference value. If the OP wishes a time delta with 1/1/2001, that's a matter of basic arithmetic given the time delta with 1/1/1970.

Comment: I know. I'm just clarifying. :)